# How to set bytea_output to hex?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, phppgadmin

I cannot seem to change `bytea_output` to `hex`.

I have tried [this method](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BEDD02CA-A662-48B6-82E5-E1F924C08724@mac.com):

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET bytea_output TO 'hex';
```

I have tried to edit postgresql.conf

```
bytea_output = 'hex'
```

and restarted the server.

I have tried

```
SET bytea_output = 'hex'
```

and it works per transaction, but that is very tedious.

However, whenever I browse my bytea columns in phpPgAdmin, the columns are outputted escaped.

This

```
SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'bytea_output'
```

returns `escape`.

How can `bytea_output` be set permanently to `hex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like PhpPgAdmin is probably doing a session-level `SET bytea_output = 'escape'`.

If you open a new psql session and `SHOW bytea_output;` it'll be hex there.

PhpPgAdmin may offer a way to control this behaviour, or it might be hard-coded to work around compatibility issues (if it doesn't understand the hex format for bytea).

Comment: Yep, you're right.  Under `Variables`, it's `escape`.  It's not in any of the `.config` files it lists.  I think it might be deep in a `.php`.  Oh, well.  Thank you so much for your help!